# Strip Comments from XML

Tags: .net, regex, comments, strip

I've encountered the need to remove comments of the form:

```
<!--  Foo

      Bar  -->
```

I'd like to use a regular expression that matches anything (including line breaks) between the beginning and end 'delimiters.'

What would a good regex be for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way :

```
Regex xmlCommentsRegex = new Regex("<!--.*?-->", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

And a better way :

```
Regex xmlCommentsRegex = new Regex("<!--(?:[^-]|-(?!->))*-->", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: For my simple test case, <!--(?:[^-]|-(?!->))*--> is equivalent to my own:  <!--([\s\S]*?)-->

Is mine missing something?

Comment: There is difference only in performance. According to my tests yours takes 118 steps to complete while mine takes 62 :)

Comment: i don't know about .net's regex library but many regex compilers have optimizations for .*? so that it's much faster than the naive case

Answer (score 6):

NONE. It cannot be described by the context free grammar, which the regular expression is based upon.

Let's say this thread is exported in XML. Your example (<!-- FOO Bar -->), if enclosed in CDATA, will be lost, while it's not exactly a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The 'proper' way would be to use XSLT and copy everything but comments.

Comment: I have not much experience with XSLT - but that's something I might try in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML with regex is considered bad style.
Use some XML parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some complete sample code to read an XML file in, and return a string which is the file with no comments.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("c:\file.xml");
{ 
  const string strRegex = @"<!--(?:[^-]|-(?!->))*-->";
  const RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
  Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
  string strTargetString = text;
  const string strReplace = @""; 

  string result = myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
  return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, `RegexOptions.Multiline` alone will not do the trick (which is slightly counterintuitive).